# error: unknown type name and warning: implicit declaration of function

Tags: c

I'm having problem implementing queue in c using linked list. I've been reading so many other questions on it here in stackoverflow and in other websites as well, but I still don't know how to fix this issue of my code yet. Anyone, please, help me?
here, it is my code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct elem{
    int n;
    elem *prox;
};

struct fila{
    elem *inicio, *fim;
}nop;

void iniciar(fila *d){
    d->inicio = (elem*) malloc(sizeof(elem));
    d->fim = (elem*) malloc(sizeof(elem));
    d->inicio->prox = d->fim;
    d->fim->prox = NULL;
}

void inserir(fila *d, int x){
    elem *novo = (elem*) malloc(sizeof(elem));
    novo->n = x;
    novo->fim->prox = NULL;

    if(d->inicio->prox == NULL)
        d->inicio->prox = novo;
    else{
        d->fim->prox = novo;
        d->fim = novo;
    }
}

void deletar(fila *d){
    if(d->inicio->prox = NULL)
        printf("Lista vazia")
    else{
        elem *apg;
        apg = d->inicio->prox;
        d->inicio->prox = apg->prox;
        printf("%d", d->n);
        free(apg);
    }
}

int main(){
    int x;

    iniciar(&nop);

    scanf("%d", &x);

    inserir(&nop, x);

    deletar(&nop);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. This question doesn't have enough real detail to it. Please put error information in the body of the question and use the title to give a general description. Also, give some examples of what you've tried. It's really difficult to answer questions without proper context.

Comment: 1) need using `typedef` in C.

Comment: I just tried compiling your code. It's not even a logical (or maybe it is) but it does not even compile. I suggest you fix all the compilation issues first and come back with a real question, i.e., stating what exactly is wrong, where things go wrong and what piece of code is relevant, and produce a minimal working example. I get a dozen or so compilation issues with what you gave us. Until then, I vote to close the question as too broad. And you should also read about typedef

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is pretty vague, however I do see one problme in this, which is that you're getting tags and typedef's confused. For example:

```
void inserir(fila *d, int x)
```

should actually be defined as

```
void inserir(struct fila *d, int x)
```

because you defined fila as a tag. The other alternative is to declare the structure fila with the typedef keyword (liek the below)

```
typedef struct elem{
int n;
struct elem *prox;
} element;

typename struct {
element *inicio, *fim;
}fila nop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the errors in this code are because you use `elem` and `fila` as type names.  Those types however are not defined.  When referencing a `struct` type, you need to prefix it with the `struct` keyword.

You can get around this by adding a `typedef` for each one so that they may be referenced by just the type name:

```
typedef struct elem elem;
typedef struct fila fila;
```

Put these lines at the top of your source file after the includes.  That will address most of the compilation issues.  The rest you should be able to figure out yourself.

Comment: I've tried it before, but it still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @JeffersonCarlosLimadaCosta It won't fix *all* the problems (you're also referencing invalid members, missing semicolon, etc) but it fixes the ones you mentioned in the question.  If you don't understand any new errors you are getting, update your question with the modified code (but don't remove the existing code) and the new errors.